# How to make Authorization server in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, authorization, spring-authorization-server

when I made a simple authorization server with `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:1.2.2` library.

I found a document on https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference

And I tried to do like this document....

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests( ( authorize ) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers( "/oauth2/**" ).authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic( Customizer.withDefaults() )
                .formLogin( Customizer.withDefaults() )
                .cors( httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.disable())
                .csrf( httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable());


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings(  ){

        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .issuer( "http://localhost:8000" )
                .tokenEndpoint( "/oauth2/v1/token" )
                .tokenIntrospectionEndpoint( "/oauth2/v1/verify" )
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService(){
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(){

        RegisteredClient client = RegisteredClient.withId( UUID.randomUUID().toString() )
                .clientId( "user" )
                .clientSecret( "{noop}user" )
                .clientAuthenticationMethod( ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC )
                .authorizationGrantType( AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE )
                .authorizationGrantType( AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS )
                .authorizationGrantType( AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN )
                .redirectUri( "http://localhost:8000/redirect" )
                .tokenSettings( TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenTimeToLive( Duration.ofDays( 1 ) ).build() )
                .clientSettings( ClientSettings.builder()
                        .build() )
                .build();


        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository( client );
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
                new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();

        http.apply( authorizationServerConfigurer );

        authorizationServerConfigurer
                .tokenEndpoint( Customizer.withDefaults() )
                .tokenGenerator( new OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator() )
                .authorizationServerSettings( authorizationServerSettings( ) )
                .registeredClientRepository( registeredClientRepository() )
                .authorizationService( authorizationService() );
//              .setBuilder( http );


        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Here is my configuration code.

And I checked basic token authentication was applied.

but when i called token endpoint url ("http://localhost:8000/oauth2/v1/token) with grant_type = client_credentials, the server return 404 error.

I couldn't find why they return 404 error.

please let me know how to set token url.

here is my debug log.

```
2024-02-27T16:07:12.942+09:00 DEBUG 84973 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/v1/token
2024-02-27T16:07:13.147+09:00 DEBUG 84973 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2024-02-27T16:07:13.148+09:00 DEBUG 84973 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
2024-02-27T16:07:13.150+09:00 DEBUG 84973 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /oauth2/v1/token
2024-02-27T16:07:13.161+09:00 DEBUG 84973 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-02-27T16:07:13.161+09:00 DEBUG 84973 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
```

Comment: I include debug log when i tried to access /oauth2/v1/token.

Comment: Your post request is not correct, so spring redirects your request to the `/error` as documented in the _Error managment_ section in the spring boot documentation on springs homepage. You need to permit `/error` to display the error message. Please take some time to read up on how error handling in spring boot works.